# Is this a good way of sending multiple mails at once in Laravel?

Tags: laravel, email, laravel-mail

I am still learning Laravel, and need some advice...
Long story short, I have a small script which is supposed to send a mail to a customer 15 days before their contract needs renewal. Now, the code does work. And our list of customers is relatively small. However, I am curious. Is this a good way of doing it? Is it efficient? Would it be a better idea to use a database query?
Anyways, here is the code...

```
    $hosting=hosting::where('id','>',0);
    $dateToday=date('Y-m-d');
    $inFifteenDays=date('Y-m-d', strtotime($dateToday. ' + 15 days'));
    $hosting=$hosting->whereDate('datum_obnove','<=',($inFifteenDays));
    $hosting=$hosting->whereDate('datum_obnove','>=',($inFifteenDays))->get();
    foreach ($hosting as $hosting) 
    {
        $dataForSending=array();
        $dataForSending= array(
            'klijent' =>$hosting['kontakt'] , 
            'domena' =>$hosting['naziv_domene'],
            'mail' =>$hosting['mail']  
        );
    Mail::to($dataForSending['mail'])->queue(new HostingMail($hosting));
    }
```

Thanks in advance <3

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Welcome to StackOverflow!

There really are [a lot of factors into when it's worth optimizing code before you hit an issue](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/80084/is-premature-optimization-really-the-root-of-all-evil), but it looks like you're already utilizing Laravel queues which is a great first step. You'll at least be able to monitor your queues (https://horizon.laravel.com/ if you choose to use it) to see if they are getting bogged down or if there are issues. The former suggestion will need you to install [Redis](https://redis.io/).

If there are issues, you could tinker with [rate limiting](https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/queues#rate-limiting) to ensure that your application is still handling performance just fine.

These suggestions are still above and beyond right now. I would recommend starting with what you have, monitoring performance, and use the above suggestions if necessary. Best of luck!

Comment: @ImranIsak you're welcome! If this answer is satisfactory to your question, can you please click the checkmark next to my answer (https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers)? Thank you. :)